# Unable to use YAML format in golang code: cannot start any token

Tags: api, authentication, go, kubernetes

I want to create a clientset in golang code to k8s cluster API and by using kubeconfig, retrieve desired resources like pods.

Due to some technical issues ,which its details are out the scope of this post, I decided to copy the kubeconfig in my code instead of loading. It's similar to:

```
object := `
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1Jg==
    server: https://122.0.0.2:3100
  name: external-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: external-cluster
    user: external-cluster
  name: external-cluster
current-context: external-cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: external-cluster
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0Z0F3SUJBZ0lJg==
    client-key-data: LQpNSUlFcEFJQkFBS0NBUUVBenVaVmVxVjhrRUc2do=
`
```

To create config object I used clientcmd package:

```
config_obj, err := clientcmd.NewClientConfigFromBytes([]byte(object))
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

After running I got error:

> panic: yaml: line 29: found character that cannot start any token

I guessed maybe there was a syntax error and tried to first unmarshal the yaml

```
var conf map[string]interface{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(object), &conf)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

But the error still persisted. I even pasted the yaml to the page so that there is no space between the yaml and the beginning of the line. What is the problem?

Note that I also tried with JSON format as well, which was not the solution.

Comment: The yaml example that you've provided doesn't have 29 lines, so the error cannot possibly come from it. How are we supposed to know what's wrong with the actual yaml if all you care to show us is only "similar" yaml?

Comment: Inside the actual code with all stuffs, panic error is in line 29. And similar means I didn't share the real URL of cluster's server or the right caDATA. I don't think the question is related to these

Comment: By *"But the error still persisted."*, do you mean that the `yaml.Unmarshal` code failed the same way as the `NewClientConfigFromBytes` code? If yes, then the yaml data that you've provided does not result in that error, see https://go.dev/play/p/edGMW6FoZ5s.

Comment: The error is not in the process of unmarshaling, it's in clientcmd functions. After unmarshalling there are more steps to create a clientset which I did. But once I tried to run `config_obj, err := clientcmd.NewClientConfigFromBytes([]byte(object))`, I got error: cannot start any token.